# keeping all result in a single list in linq C#?

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

Using the simple example below,I aim to keep linq results within same list:

```
     for (int j = 0; j < YatakList.Count; j++)
        {
            if (YatakList[j].GrupId != Op.yatakGrupId)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var AllBlanks = YatakList[j].blanks
                .SelectMany((item, index) => 
                    item.Select(entry => new 
                    { 
                        Index = index, 
                        Start = entry.Key, 
                        Length = entry.Value, 
                        Id = YatakList[j].Id, 
                        GrupId = YatakList[j].GrupId 
                    }))
                .OrderBy(item => item.Start);
            var LenghtSuitingBlanks = from blank in AllBlanks 
                where (blank.Length >= Op.sure) 
                select blank;
            var closestDiff = LenghtSuitingBlanks.First();

        }
```

By using for loop I get first result from YatakList,but within second case (j=1) of for loop altought I get the second result set I am loosing the first one.
My Question is :

How can I keep the result set of linq in a list 
OR

Is there a alternative way (preferred solution) that does not use for loop

Comment: Since you've declared all the results of your queries as local variables *inside* the loop, where did you expect the results to go?

Comment: I'm reading your example and I can't quite figure out what you are trying to do?  Do you need all banks, from the YatakList that is not in the Op.GroupId?

Comment: AllBlanks retrn type is anonymous , I want to keep the result set in the List defined before the for loop. Or All elements in YatakList keeps blanks in type of dictionary Is there an alternative solution that returns all result in YatakList

Comment: I think what you're trying to say is re-sort the same List Collection that you have. I can't figure out what you're doing in your code.

Comment: Let me explain my problem more obivious:

Comment: Let me explain my problem obviously: I have a List(YatakList) that contains object kaynak , this object own a Dictionary<int, int> type named blank.I have already write an LINQ code that gets result from all element of list by using for loop. Actually I don't prefer to use for loop Is tehre an global solution that returns all AllBlank ? In my code AllBlanks gets just for 1 Iteration of for loop, I need a list that contains AllBlanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by crating an class named UygunYatak then by the help of another loop collect all elements in a List.

```
       for (int i = 0; i < YatakList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (YatakList[i].GrupId != Op.yatakGrupId)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var AllBlanks = YatakList[i].blanks.SelectMany((item, index) => item.Select(entry => new { Index = index, Start = entry.Key, Length = entry.Value, Id = YatakList[i].Id, GrupId = YatakList[i].GrupId })).OrderBy(item => item.Start);
            var LenghtSuitingBlanks = from blank in AllBlanks where (blank.Length >= Op.sure) orderby blank.Start select blank;

            for (int j = 0; j < LenghtSuitingBlanks.Count(); j++)
            {
                UygunYatak uygunYatak = new UygunYatak();
                uygunYatak.Id = LenghtSuitingBlanks.ElementAt(j).Id;
                uygunYatak.GrupId = LenghtSuitingBlanks.ElementAt(j).GrupId;
                uygunYatak.Start = LenghtSuitingBlanks.ElementAt(j).Start;
                uygunYatak.Length = LenghtSuitingBlanks.ElementAt(j).Length;

                UygunYatakList.Add(uygunYatak);
            }
        }

public class UygunYatak
{
    public int Id;
    public int GrupId;
    public int Start;
    public int Length;
}
```